# Codeigniter DB date_format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and I made a query like this.

```
$this->db->select("first_name as 'First Name', last_name as 'Last Name', phone as 'Phone', os.group as 'Group', gender as 'Gender', birth_date as 'DOB', email as 'Email', street_address as 'Address', city as 'City', province as 'Province', postal_code as 'Postal Code', country 'Country', payment_amount as 'Payment Amount', DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as 'Payment Date', an.notes as 'Notes'");
                $this->db->join('athlete_notes an', 'os.id = an.id', 'inner');
                $this->db->group_by(array("first_name", "last_name"));
                $this->db->order_by("last_name asc, first_name asc");
                $query = $this->db->get('offline_shoppers os');
```

and get this csv output:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=members_list.csv");
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");
                echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
```

I am trying to format the payment_date to d/m/Y but DATE_FORMAT gave me errors:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`offline_shoppers` os) INNER JOIN `athlete_notes` an ON `os`.`id` = `an`.`' at line 2
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select("first_name as 'First Name', last_name as 'Last Name', phone as 'Phone', os.group as 'Group', gender as 'Gender', birth_date as 'DOB', email as 'Email', street_address as 'Address', city as 'City', province as 'Province', postal_code as 'Postal Code', country 'Country', payment_amount as 'Payment Amount', DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%d/%m/%Y') as 'Payment Date', an.notes as 'Notes'");
                $this->db->from('offline_shoppers as os');//
                $this->db->join('athlete_notes as an', 'os.id = an.id', 'inner');//
                $this->db->group_by(array("first_name", "last_name"));
                $this->db->order_by("last_name asc, first_name asc");
                $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (`offline_shoppers` os) INNER JOIN `athlete_notes` an ON `os`.`id` = `an`.`' at line 2`

Comment: CODE:`$this->db->from('offline_shoppers os');
                $this->db->join('athlete_notes an', 'os.id = an.id', 'inner');
                $this->db->group_by(array("first_name", "last_name"));
                $this->db->order_by("last_name asc, first_name asc");
                $query = $this->db->get();`

Comment: I have edited two lines code.please try with this one.
$this->db->from('offline_shoppers as os');//
$this->db->join('athlete_notes as an', 'os.id = an.id', 'inner');//

Comment: If this not works perfectly then print your query which return raw query and run from phpmyadmin panel.It helps you to find out actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

First run this raw sql query in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT first_name AS 'First Name', last_name AS 'Last Name', phone AS 'Phone', os.group AS 'Group', gender AS 'Gender',
 birth_date AS 'DOB', email AS 'Email', street_address AS 'Address', city AS 'City', province AS 'Province', 
 postal_code AS 'Postal Code', country 'Country', payment_amount AS 'Payment Amount', 
 DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Payment Date', an.notes AS 'Notes'
FROM offline_shoppers os              
    INNER JOIN athlete_notes an ON (os.id = an.id)
    GROUP BY first_name,last_name
    ORDER BY  last_name ASC, first_name ASC
```

if no errors found then

```
$this->db->query("
SELECT first_name AS 'First Name', last_name AS 'Last Name', phone AS 'Phone', os.group AS 'Group', gender AS 'Gender',
 birth_date AS 'DOB', email AS 'Email', street_address AS 'Address', city AS 'City', province AS 'Province', 
 postal_code AS 'Postal Code', country 'Country', payment_amount AS 'Payment Amount', 
 DATE_FORMAT(payment_date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Payment Date', an.notes AS 'Notes'
FROM offline_shoppers os              
    INNER JOIN athlete_notes an ON (os.id = an.id)
    GROUP BY first_name,last_name
    ORDER BY  last_name ASC, first_name ASC ")->result();
```